# Style pieces of text that's not wrapped in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently pulling in data from an API using a SOAP call.

I end up with html that looks like so:

```
<div class="component_wrapper">
2 man Teams<br>
20 Min AMRAP<br>
50 Double Unders<br>
50 Push Ups<br>
50 Toes 2 Bar<br>
50 Push Press 95/65<br>
50 Heavy Lunges 45/25<br>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to style two parts of this differently. The numbers and the descriptions. If I wrap all the numbers in a span, then I'll style things like "95/65" which I don't want to do.

Here's my logic:
Everything BEFORE the first space, wrap in `<span class="count"></span>`and everything AFTER the first space wrap in `<span class="description"></span>`. The space itself can be removed. If no space, wrap in `<span class="description"></span>`.

My thought behind this is, if there is a long number like 1000, It'll still get that wrapped, but if there is no number, It'll just style the other half like I would a description.

Is something like this possible? The only code I could find that was similar to doing this is:

```
str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')); // "2"
str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1); // "man Teams"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use a regular expression that looks for 1 or more digits at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the lines, using regex to parse out the numbers and put them into the correct spans:

```
var text=element.innerHTML,newtext="";
text=text.split("<br>");
for(var i=0,l=text.length;i<l;i++){
    newtext+=text.replace(/^(\d*)\s(.*)$/,"<span class='count'>$1</span><span class="description">$2</span><br/>");
}
element.innerHTML=newtext;
```

**Working Version**

```
var text=document.getElementById('wod').innerHTML;
var newtext="";
text=text.split("<br>");
for(var i=0,l=text.length;i<l;i++){
    newtext+=text[i].replace(/(\d*)\s(.*)$/,"<span class='count'>$1</span><span class='description'>$2</span><br/>");
}
document.getElementById('wod').innerHTML=newtext;
```

Comment: @HenryBayuzick, Your first problem is that `getElementsByClassName` wants `component_wrapper`, not `.componenet_wrapper`.  Second, `getElementsByClassName` returns a (pseudo-)array, not an element; you need to use `[0]`.  You're error is that the array returned by `getElementsByClassName` doesn't have a `innerHTML` attribute.

Comment: This worked for the most part, but I had to make some syntax changes to get it to execute. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `span`s don't have a height:

```
'2 man Teams'.replace(/^(\d)+\s(.*)$/, "<span class='count'>$1</span><span class='description'>$2</span>";
```